# Uninstall Amplify CLI with Curl

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I have installed Amplify CLI with curl and npm, I which to keep one, so I'm uninstalling curl just because in my personal case npm is easier for me to update, this is the command I used to install it:

```
curl -sL https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-cli/install | bash && $SHELL
```

How can I uninstall it? I'm using macOS

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clean up manually seems to me which isnt that hard though.

Binary is located in `$HOME/.amplify/bin/amplify`. Then depending on your shell you can remove the custom path and configuration added by the  [installation script](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-cli/install).

```sh
# Add to $PATH
SOURCE_STR="# Added by Amplify CLI binary installer\nexport PATH=\"\$HOME/.amplify/bin:\$PATH\"\n"
add_to_path () {
  command printf "\n$SOURCE_STR" >> "$1"
  printf "\n$yellow Added the following to $1:\n\n$SOURCE_STR$reset"
}
SHELLTYPE="$(basename "/$SHELL")"
if [[ $SHELLTYPE = "fish" ]]; then
  command fish -c 'set -U fish_user_paths ~/.amplify/bin $fish_user_paths'
  printf "\n$yellow Added ~/.amplify/bin to fish_user_paths universal variable$reset."
elif [[ $SHELLTYPE = "zsh" ]]; then
  SHELL_CONFIG=$HOME/.zshrc
  if [ ! -r $SHELL_CONFIG ] || (! `grep -q '.amplify/bin' $SHELL_CONFIG`); then
    add_to_path $SHELL_CONFIG
  fi
else
  SHELL_CONFIG=$HOME/.bashrc
  if [ ! -r $SHELL_CONFIG ] || (! `grep -q '.amplify/bin' $SHELL_CONFIG`); then
    add_to_path $SHELL_CONFIG
  fi
  SHELL_CONFIG=$HOME/.bash_profile
  if [[ -r $SHELL_CONFIG ]]; then
    if [[ ! $(grep -q '.amplify/bin' $SHELL_CONFIG) ]]; then
      add_to_path $SHELL_CONFIG
    fi
  else
    SHELL_CONFIG=$HOME/.bash_login
    if [[ -r $SHELL_CONFIG ]]; then
      if [[ ! $(grep -q '.amplify/bin' $SHELL_CONFIG) ]]; then
        add_to_path $SHELL_CONFIG
      fi
    else
      SHELL_CONFIG=$HOME/.profile
      if [ ! -r $SHELL_CONFIG ] || (! `grep -q '.amplify/bin' $SHELL_CONFIG`); then
        add_to_path $SHELL_CONFIG
      fi
    fi
  fi
fi
```